# Google Analytics is not showing Data

Tags: google, google-analytics

I am reaching you because I am unable to see data from today and I am unable to go to the main dashboard after logging in, it has automatically redirected to the admin panel. I do not understand why this is happening.

I have posted a [question on the google analytics community](https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/108830953/google-analytics-is-not-showing-data) but I haven't received any response yet and that's why I have raised my question here. I have tried using a different web browser as well as a mobile app but the issue is the same, data is not showing in Google analytics.

I have also attached a google analytics screenshot.[image]

Please help me!

Comment: Have you tried a different report? Are there's any flagged items needing attention in the admin interface? What's the outstanding notification you have? Have you tried a hard-refresh (pressing shift+F5)?

Comment: Yes, I haven't received any notification yet regarding the account details and I tried many time hard refresh but the result is the same. I do not understand what's wrong with google analytics. Please help me

Comment: You have a notification in Analytics (the little bell icon in the top right). It's only "yellow" so it's unlikely to be anything related to your problem, but it's worth a look. I've never encountered a problem where the admin dashboard wouldn't close, but if I had to guess then I'd have to say that you might have an issue with one of your settings that Google needs to fix before you continue. Failing that, logging out and in again might help. Also, if you have access to another Analytics property, can you access that?

Comment: Notification that I have seen on GA is

Comment: Notification that I have seen on GA is https://imgur.com/a/rcnVzfV. 

Yes, I have access to another analytics property where data is being shown properly except this account, I logged in and out of google analytics account many times with different browsers and cleared cookies but the problem wouldn't solve till now. I do not understand what's wrong with this account. I checked the data yesterday everything was fine. I didn't change anything. Please help.

Comment: [Let's take this to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123891/google-analytics-is-not-showing-data), which is more appropriate than extending this comments section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123924/discussion-between-olivia-and-geoffatkins).